# xcode 8 : Issue Navigator resets compiler warnings --> timer setting?

Tags: ios, xcode

After a clean and build the Issue Navigator shows the current list of compiler issues.  But, it times out after several minutes.  It can sometimes be refreshed by tapping a line.  Tapping the error icons, or querying the menus or other quick actions from the pulldowns don't perform a refresh.  This disrupts the workflow by needing a full rebuild to enable errors to be seen.  Is there a timer or other preference to change this behavior?